# Android Studio - Probably the SDK is read-only - error persists

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-studio-3.0

Have been developing android apps using Microsoft Visual Studio and now installed Android Studio.

Pretty much anything I try to do, like creating a new app, installing support for a new API level, etc, is getting held up by the same thing - error messages in the log - Probably the SDK is read-only.

Since I am doing this on a Windows 10 PC, the base folder where Android SDK is installed is C:\Program Files(x86)... I have created a link to this folder using mkdir and referred to this in visual studio so my SDK folder reads C:\android-SDK. That way I don't get problems with the spaces in the folder path, which NDK hates...

Now, when I try to make the android-SDK folder NOT read-only, it keeps reverting back to read-only automatically. I checked that I am the owner of this folder.

Going crazy with this now.

Appreciate help on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

Of course the initial Android SDK location is read-only for regular user since it is placed in Program Files.
I don't think you can work around this limitation with links to subfolders since it defeats the whole idea of restricting access rights for Program Files. I'd create a folder, not link, somewhere and reinstall (or copy, if that would work - I don't know) Android SDK there.